# Can I use pg_dumpall withtout installing postgresQL?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

I tried in my docker container(from alpine3.6) to run command to install pg_dumpall I've seen in the web:

```
apk update && apk upgrade
```

and then

```
apk add --no-cache postgresql-client-common
```

and finally

```
apk add --no-cache postgresql-client
```

Only the last of the two installs I tried worked (the one without common) but I still won't have `pg_dump` or `pg_dumpall` in my binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each alpine version has different postgresql-client. For myself I wrote those logic:

```
ARG PSQL_VERSION=0
RUN if [ "$PSQL_VERSION" = "13" ]; then \
        echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    elif [ "$PSQL_VERSION" = "12" ]; then \
        echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    elif [ "$PSQL_VERSION" = "11" ]; then \
        echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    elif [ "$PSQL_VERSION" = "10" ]; then \
            echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories; \
    fi
RUN apk update
RUN apk --no-cache add postgresql-client
```

And now you can pass needed client version:

```
docker build -t backuper --build-arg PSQL_VERSION=12 .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to

`apk add postgresql-client`

You can see all included binaries of this package in this link. This package has a pg_dumpall

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=postgresql-client&branch=v3.8&repo=main&arch=aarch64

Comment: I already tried with apk as u can see in my post but the binary won't be found anyway

Comment: what is your alpine image version?

Comment: FROM alpine 3.6

Comment: try change to alpine 3.8. I sure this tool consist inside postgresql-client

Comment: As you can see the alpine 3.6 doesn't consist pg_dump binary

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=postgresql-client&branch=v3.6&repo=main&arch=aarch64